# Could someone be nice enough to add windows-7-starter as a tag to superuser.com?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, tags

I would do it but I only have 150 rep.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As I said on chat: We really don't create new tags for such a small subject area - the tag [windows-7](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows-7) is enough...

by the way, there is no rep earned on Super User Meta.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Furthermore: The questions for Windows 7 Starter are very limited as besides the borders of that edition the rest would just apply to the `windows-7` tag.

Comment: I support this answer.  We are trying to keep tags clean and consistent.